# Monitor outgoing web requests as they’re happening

Tags: networking, monitoring, http, https, privacy

I want to see a list of all outgoing HTTP requests from my desktop. I think it should be possible to monitor HTTPS hostnames as well for local clients using Server Name Indication (SNI).

OS X has a nice GUI utility called [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html), which is a per-app HTTP monitor and firewall rule front-end.

I would settle for a nice terminal utility. `tcpdump` is overkill as I just want to see where the traffic is going in real-time and not the transmitted data. Ideally, I would like to see what process made the request as well, but just seeing what dials home would be a nice start.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `lsof` and `watch` to do this, like so:

```
$ watch -n1 lsof -i TCP:80,443
```

#### Example output

```
dropbox    3280 saml   23u  IPv4 56015285      0t0  TCP greeneggs.qmetricstech.local:56003->snt-re3-6c.sjc.dropbox.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
thunderbi  3306 saml   60u  IPv4 56093767      0t0  TCP greeneggs.qmetricstech.local:34788->ord08s09-in-f20.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
mono       3322 saml   15u  IPv4 56012349      0t0  TCP greeneggs.qmetricstech.local:54018->204-62-14-135.static.6sync.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
chrome    11068 saml  175u  IPv4 56021419      0t0  TCP greeneggs.qmetricstech.local:42182->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [Creek's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144004/97255) (whilst also using part of it) is to dispense with `watch`, and use the `-r` option to `lsof` instead, to end up with a repetitive log scrolling up the terminal, for example

```
lsof -i TCP:80,443 -r 1
```

which repeats every one second, and each repeat's output is separated by `=======`. It may not be as pretty, but it gives a scrollable history, for example:

```
=======
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 9542 user   27u  IPv4 1068219      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:37360->192.0.78.23:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   48u  IPv4 1053405      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:45948->ec2-54-213-37-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
=======
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 9542 user   27u  IPv4 1068219      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:37360->192.0.78.23:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   48u  IPv4 1053405      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:45948->ec2-54-213-37-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   52u  IPv4 1138942      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:57602->kul08s01-in-f10.1e100.net:https (SYN_SENT)
firefox 9542 user  102u  IPv4 1139934      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:49102->kul09s13-in-f14.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user  110u  IPv4 1138950      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:49104->kul09s13-in-f14.1e100.net:https (SYN_SENT)
=======
...
=======
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 9542 user   27u  IPv4 1068219      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:37360->192.0.78.23:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   48u  IPv4 1053405      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:45948->ec2-54-213-37-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   51u  IPv4 1140129      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:52284->kul09s13-in-f10.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user  108u  IPv4 1137384      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:55886->103.229.10.236:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user  122u  IPv4 1137399      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:55870->kul08s12-in-f1.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user  126u  IPv4 1137402      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:47370->stackoverflow.com:https (SYN_SENT)
```

Note: I only had Firefox open, so only one application is showing.

Obviously this output could be redirected or piped to a (log) file.